# TestNG how to build a queue of test cases to be retried

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework, testng

Currently, we have logic in place which retries all the failing test cases immediately after the failure, what could be any approach where if a test fails that test should go in a queue and should be retried when all other test cases are executed at least once.

our current logic works like following-

```
private static int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = ExecutionConfig.TEST_CASE_RETRY_COUNT;
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(MAX_RETRY_COUNT);

@Override
        public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
            boolean retry = false;
            if (count.intValue() > 0) {
                retry = true;
                count.decrementAndGet();
            }
            return retry;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what TestNG does not support "natively". However here is some example that shows how you can approximately approach to your problem:

**DISCLAIMER:** There is no warranty that this would be working for any other real use-case except of the given example:

```java
package click.webelement.testng.rerun;

import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RerunTest{

    static int retries = 0;
    final static int MAX_RETRIES = 2;

    @Test
    public void successfulTest(){
        System.out.println("Success");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    void failedTest(){
        System.out.println("Failed test");
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void anotherSuccessfulTest(){
        System.out.println("Another one success");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    void anotherFailedTest(){
        System.out.println("Another failed test");
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }


    @AfterClass
    public void retry(ITestContext cntx){
        if(retries < MAX_RETRIES){
            TestNG testng = new TestNG();                        // This is the tricky thing
            testng.setTestClasses(new Class[]{this.getClass()}); // If you know how to obtain current executor, you will work around this
            testng.setMethodInterceptor(new IMethodInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
                    List<IMethodInstance> toRerun = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(IMethodInstance methodInstance: methods){
                        if(cntx.getFailedTests().getAllMethods().stream().anyMatch(t -> t.getMethodName().equals(methodInstance.getMethod().getMethodName()))){
                            toRerun.add(methodInstance);
                        }
                    }
                    return toRerun;
                }
            });
            retries++;
            System.out.println("Retrying: " + cntx.getFailedTests().getAllMethods().stream().map(t -> t.getMethodName()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            testng.run();
        }
    }

}
```

This will likely use different context for your rerun tests so that you will likely run into issues with reporting and many other things.

Comment: yup it worked but will generate a separate report so this logic needs improvement. I am working on a workaround, will post here if I will get success